# Hide "Display URL" on OData/External Object global search results?

Tags: lightning-connect, global-search, odata

Is it possible to not display the column "Display URL" within the Global Search page when displaying OData/External Object/Lightning Connect results?  The field is not in the External Object's Search Layout section but shows up on the Global Search result page.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize search results form the search layout setting in the external object detail (very similar to configuring any standard/ custom object search settings in salesforce)

Note: Display URL can be removed, extrenal Id cannot be removed from the search layout.

**Update: 
This answer does not work: Display URL shows up and seems to me like a salesforce bug**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I confirmed that the Display URL was not on any Search Layouts before posting.  I even tried adding the Display URL and pushing it to the end of the list but it still shows up in the 2nd spot no matter what.

Comment: I did try to hide the displayURL but unable to, definitely a bug